# How to replicate / get current user notifications in Buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, notifications, buddypress

How to replicate buddypress notifications that are in menu? I already have the avatar and the domain, but am not finding solutions for getting the notification count + url to current user ID's notifications.

Answer (score 1):

This funtions return the notification count for a user id:

```
bp_notifications_get_unread_notification_count(bp_loggedin_user_id());
```

and this return the notifications:

```
bp_notifications_get_notifications_for_user(bp_loggedin_user_id());
```